# Are there specific names for and objections to "no miracles - no deity" argument?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-religion

"[Holy book] claims that [deity] performed many miracles in the past, and thus made their existence obvious. Therefore, [deity] would have no problems performing miracles these days. Miracles aren't performed these days. Therefore, [holy book] is probably wrong about the miracles, and thus [deity] most likely doesn't exist."

[Argument from nonbelief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_nonbelief) seems close, but I don't think it's similar enough to this argument to count.

Comment: "probably wrong about the miracles, and thus [deity] most likely doesn't exist" seems like a plain non-sequitur. Even assuming that a book is wrong about the miracles and about the deity there is no logical connection to deity's existence.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the additional words in the argument, the most obvious flaw is the presumption that a deity that CAN perform miracles at any point WILL perform them at any point.  It could be thought of as an underestimation of the agency of the deity.

A counter example has to be tailored to the audience.  For a science audience, an argument revolving around the Drake equation may be a reasonable analog.  It has a similar pattern of an event happening in the past but not being recorded as happening in recent times.

A less contentious example which could work for any religion might be with regard to someone who used to make a killing playing high stakes poker with a unique talent of reading people's tells, but no longer plays.  Therefore, that person probably didn't ever know how to read tells in the first place.